# Selenium element is not clickable even after excplicitly waiting for it to be

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to open a form, wait for all of it's elements to be loaded and fill one of the form's fields.
Form is loading, and I'm setting a WebdriverWait to explicitly wait for my element to be clickable.
But on elem.click() I get exception

```
Element...is not clickable at the point
```

Code sample I'm using:

```
def fill_element(driver, xpath, keys, secs=2000):
   print(f"\nFilling for {xpath}...")
   elem = WebDriverWait(driver, secs).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath)))
   elem.clear()
   elem.click()
   elem.send_keys("")
   elem.send_keys(keys)
```

If I don't use "click" and just trying to send keys - nothing happens. No exceptions and no form filling.

Could someone please advise how to use Wait properly?

P.S. Window was maximized even before clicking on the form to open, so it shoudln't be the problem.

**UPD** Full code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from pathlib import Path
import time

def fill_element(driver, xpath, keys, secs=2000):
   print(f"\nFilling for {xpath}...")
   element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
   driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).send_keys("test")


def authorize(driver):
   email = "xxx"
   pwd = "xxx"
   my_acc_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='menuOverride showLoginPopUp menu-account-icon']")
   my_acc_button.click()

   email_xpath = "// INPUT[@ type='email']"
   fill_element(driver, email_xpath, email)
   pwd_xpath = "// INPUT[@ type='password']"
   fill_element(driver, pwd_xpath, pwd)

   login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='btn green-color']")
   # login_button.click()


driver_path = r'D:\Projects\cheater_buster_parser\utils\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()

start_url = 'https://www.cheaterbuster.net/'
driver.get(start_url)
authorize(driver)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to new updates, use the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from pathlib import Path
import time

def fill_element(driver, xpath, keys, secs=2000):
   print(f"\nFilling for {xpath}...")
   element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
   driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).send_keys("test")


def authorize(driver):
   email = "xxx"
   pwd = "xxx"
   my_acc_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='menuOverride showLoginPopUp menu-account-icon']")
   my_acc_button.click()

   email_xpath = "(//INPUT[@type='email'])[2]"
   fill_element(driver, email_xpath, email)
   pwd_xpath = "(//INPUT[@type='password'])[3]"
   fill_element(driver, pwd_xpath, pwd)

   login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='btn green-color']")
   # login_button.click()


driver_path = r'D:\Projects\cheater_buster_parser\utils\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()

start_url = 'https://www.cheaterbuster.net/'
driver.get(start_url)
authorize(driver)
```

Comment: This code passes, but does nothing, unfortunately. Just throws warning at me for using deprecated "find_element_by_xpath" :)
Inputs are not filled.

Comment: I have edited it with another way to send values to this text , but i need to know if this xpath related to text element or button?

Comment: I have two: email and password. Currently both are not filling. Will try updated solution.

Comment: Okay Updated now

Comment: Had to fix it, since interpreter throwed errors.
After fixes, code looks like this:

def fill_element(driver, xpath, keys, secs=2000):
   print(f"\nFilling for {xpath}...")
   element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
   driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).send_keys("Your-Name")
   element.send_keys("Test Text")

but it's not filling the forms, unfortunately.

Comment: Why you write this :                  
 element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))).

Comment: Could you use the exact code in the answer

Comment: With using this exact code I'm getting exception: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 40, in <module>
    authorize(driver)
  File "main.py", line 22, in authorize
    fill_element(driver, email_xpath, email)
  File "main.py", line 12, in fill_element
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).sendKeys("Your-Name")
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement'. Did you mean: 'find_element'?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).send_keys("test")

Comment: Now passes, but still not filling.

Comment: Send the webpage or url

Comment: 'https://www.cheaterbuster.net/'
Login form shows after clicking on "My account".

Comment: Please use: 
1-Email Xpath: (//INPUT[@type='email'])[2]
2-Password :  (//INPUT[@type='password'])[3]

Comment: Still nothing. I posted full code in the original question. Could you please review it?
I used almost the same xpathes, except they were not in caps.

Comment: Now it works!
Thank you very much for your help!
So, it looks like there were multiple inputs on the page, somehow. And I was pointing to wrong ones. Correct?
Visually I didn't notice any others and was sure there is only one set.

Answer (score 1):

Use the foloowing code but make sure if this element is button to click or text field then send keys to it. (According to your info i think its text field

```
def fill_element(driver, xpath, keys, secs=2000):
   print(f"\nFilling for {xpath}...")
   element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xpath")))
   elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
   elem.clear()
   elem.click()
   elem.send_keys("")
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer!
This approach really waits. but I'm getting TimeOutException, for some reason.
Are there may be common reasons for such behavior?

Comment: Yes , may be cause of couldn't find the element , could you write details of TimeOutException

Comment: Sure. Posted in original question, since I can't use styling in the comment.

Comment: Try to write the time in number instead of secs

Comment: You can use following exprsion for wait method:

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

emailFieldElement = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(emailFieldId))
passFieldElement = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(passFieldId))

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Also, I noticed an error on my side: I just copy-pasted your solution with plain "xpath" stirng for XPATH, initially.
Using correct XPATH leads to method to NOT wait again, just raising "element not clickable" exception.

Comment: Yes , that good to find it

Comment: Text element working correctly with elem.send_keys("") ?

Comment: elem.send_keys() just does nothing. No exception, no filling.

Comment: Could you please upload last updated code

Comment: def fill_element(driver, xpath, keys, secs=2000):
   print(f"\nFilling for {xpath}...")
   elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
   print(f"\nFound elem id: {elem.id}")
   elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(lambda x: driver.find_element_by_id(elem.id))
   elem.clear()
   elem.click()
   elem.send_keys("")

This code waits, but fails with TimeOutException

Comment: I will add new replay